# Release a component instance (using Spring.NET Container)

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

What is the preferred way to release a component instance using Spring.NET Container?

*The equivalent for Castle Windsor is container.Release(Object instance)*

Comment: Note that in general you want your IoC to manage object life cycles. Why do you want to do this yourself? From what I read [here](http://kozmic.pl/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/), `container.Release` in Windsor has very specific use cases and in most cases you should not explicitly call it.

Comment: Yes, true. But sometimes I want to use the container as a Service Locator (more or less we all do that, specially when we can't afford factories).

Comment: Even when using your container as a Service Locator, you generally don't have to explicitly notify your container to release your objects; I don't see the immediate relation. However, there are scenario's where you might want to tell the container to release objects, so it's a good question.

Comment: Well sometimes it is more or less complicated, depending on the container. In Windsor, depending on the lifestyle and tracking policies, sometimes you _may_ have to release your components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't supported. There is an [(old) thread](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=525) on the Spring forum addressing this issue.

The recommended approach is to create a [context hierarchy](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#context-functionality-hierarchy), from which you release an entire context, instead of releasing individual object instances.